# Bower install malformed on mac

Tags: macos, bower

When running `bower install` on Mac it fails with:

```
bower    EMALFORMED Failed to read bower_components/jquery/.bower.json

Additional error details:
Unexpected token }
```

When viewing the file you can see that indeed there is an extra bracket at the end. It seems that these files are [generated by Bower](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1174).

It works fine on a couple Ubuntu boxes and the extra bracket is not there so not sure if it is somehow Mac specific.

We've tried to reinstall bower and `bower cache clean` with no luck. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a dependency that was referencing an exact version of jquery that was quite old and ended up with multiple versions of jquery downloaded. I fixed the jquery reference in the offending dependency and the problem resolved. I'm not sure why it only broke on one platform.